# Any way to go from uninterpreted term representative to term in z3?

Tags: c++, z3

I am using the c++ API. I create an uninterpreted and terms x, y, and z of that type.

```
z3::context ctx;
auto termSort = ctx.uninterpreted_sort("USORT");
auto x = ctx.constant("x", termSort);
auto y = ctx.constant("y", termSort);
auto z = ctx.constant("z", termSort);

solver s(ctx);
s.add(x == y);
s.add(y != z);
s.check();
auto model = s.get_model();
```

When I print the model, I get the following, which is essentially printing out the internal representatives for each term.

```
x: USORT!val!0
y: USORT!val!0
z: USORT!val!1
```

My question is: **how can I quickly go from representative to term?** I want a function like this:

```
repr_to_term(USORT!val!0) => [x, y]
repr_to_term(USORT!val!1) => [z]
```

Is there anything like this available in the Z3 API? Or a way to emulate it?

In this simple case I can simply walk all my terms and build a map from representatives to terms. But in my actual case I don't want to walk all the terms each time I generate a model, because there are a lot of terms.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used C++ API and this answer might not be what you are looking for. But in z3py we can declare variables in the following fashion

```
>>> from z3 import *
>>> for i in xrange(9):
...     globals()['a%i' % i]=BitVec('a%i' %i,8)
... 
>>> type(a0)
<type 'instance'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this information is obtained once and then used many times, the best idea is probably to generate a map, as suggested, and then use that for lookups.

Otherwise, with a little bit of refactoring, the problem would fit into [Z3_get_implied_equalities](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga9e5061818a22dfefbb64f8a5f19ec478), which solves a very similar task. Although, I'm not able to say whether that would or should perform better.